# Django: Resolving "Reverse for 'password_reset_complete' not found."

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-authentication

I am attempting to do a password reset using Django using custom html templates. I am able to request an password reset by email (using the EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'), and I then get an "email" in the console, as I would like.  The email does lead me to the "password_reset_confirm.html" page as I would like, and I can input the new passwords for the user associated with the user.

However I am getting the following error when I click the "Reset password!" button:

```
"Reverse for 'password_reset_complete' not found. 'password_reset_complete' is not a valid view function or pattern name."
```

Despite this error, the password does actually change, however I (obviously) do not want this error.

The structure of the project has a users "app" within the main structure, so it is:

project
main_app
users
----templates
--------registration
------------password_reset_form.html
------------password_reset_confirm.html
------------password_reset_done.html
------------password_reset_email.html
------------password_reset_complete.html

My code for urls.py in users is as follows:

```py
from django.urls import path, include, reverse_lazy

from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

app_name = 'users'
urlpatterns = [
    # Default authorisation urls.
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    # Registration page.
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
    # Password reset urls.
    path(
        'password_reset',
        auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
            template_name='registration/password_reset_form.html',
            email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html',
            success_url=reverse_lazy('users:password_reset_done')
        ),
        name='password_reset'
    ),
    path(
        'password_reset/done/',
        auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_reset_done.html'),
        name='password_reset_done'
    ),
    path(
        'reset/<uidb64>/<token>/',
        auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
            template_name='registration/password_reset_confirm.html',
            success_url=reverse_lazy('users:password_reset_complete.html')
        ),
        name='password_reset_confirm'
    ),
    path(
        'reset/done/',
        auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_reset_complete.html'),
        name='password_reset_complete'
    ),

]
```

I had a similar issue but with "password_reset_done", however I was able to resolve this thanks to looking through this site, by adding

```py
success_url=reverse_lazy('users:password_reset_done')
```

to the path for the password reset, and that resolved that issue, however I then bumped into a subsequent issue as above, and I haven't found any solutions that have resolved it.
Adding the following to the path for the password_reset_confirmation didn't help:

```py
success_url=reverse_lazy('users:password_reset_complete.html')
```

I tried changing this to a login page, for example, which appeared to change nothing, and on investigation found that I could remove the following and the program would be unaltered:

```py
    path(
        'reset/<uidb64>/<token>/',
        auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
            template_name='registration/password_reset_confirm.html',
            success_url=reverse_lazy('users:password_reset_complete.html')
        ),
        name='password_reset_confirm'
    ),
    path(
        'reset/done/',
        auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_reset_complete.html'),
        name='password_reset_complete'
    ),
```

Which is why the success_url in this case isn't changing the behaviour.  I'm wondering if the password_reset_email.html is the culprit, in case this is resulting in "password_reset_confirm" being called, as opposed to "user:password_reset_confirm" (because the urlpattern is being ignored).

password_reset_email.html:

```html
{% autoescape off %}
To initiate the password reset process for your account, click the link below:

{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'users:password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
If clicking the link above doesn't, please copy and paste it into a new browser instead.

{% endautoescape %}
```

I have also included the password_reset_confirm.html code in case it helps:

```html
{% extends "demeter_app/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <p>Please enter your new password:</p>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Reset password!">
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can solve this?  I've tried looking on Stackoverflow however most queries relate to password_reset_done and not **password_reset_complete**.

More of the error is below:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/users/reset/MQ/set-password/

Django Version: 3.1.7
Python Version: 3.9.2
Installed Applications:
['demeter_app',
 'users',
 'import_export',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\marcj\Documents\demeter\demeter_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\marcj\Documents\demeter\demeter_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\marcj\Documents\demeter\demeter_env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\marcj\Documents\demeter\demeter_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\marcj\Documents\demeter\demeter_env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\debug.py", line 89, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\marcj\Documents\demeter\demeter_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\marcj\Documents\demeter\demeter_env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\marcj\Documents\demeter\demeter_env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py", line 272, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\marcj\Documents\demeter\demeter_env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\marcj\Documents\demeter\demeter_env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 142, in post
    return self.form_valid(form)
  File "C:\Users\marcj\Documents\demeter\demeter_env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py", line 305, in form_valid
    return super().form_valid(form)
  File "C:\Users\marcj\Documents\demeter\demeter_env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 57, in form_valid
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
  File "C:\Users\marcj\Documents\demeter\demeter_env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 51, in get_success_url
    if not self.success_url:
  File "C:\Users\marcj\Documents\demeter\demeter_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 135, in __wrapper__
    res = func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)
  File "C:\Users\marcj\Documents\demeter\demeter_env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 87, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\marcj\Documents\demeter\demeter_env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /users/reset/MQ/set-password/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'password_reset_complete' not found. 'password_reset_complete' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Please let me know if there is anything else I can provide to help.

Comment: `'users:password_reset_complete.html'` -> `'users:password_reset_complete'`

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work for you, because Link order broken. First, the redesignated ones should go, and only then, the standard ones.
For proper operation, it is enough to do this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('password_reset/',
        auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
            success_url=reverse_lazy('users:password_reset_done')), 
        name='password_reset'),
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', 
        auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
            success_url=reverse_lazy('users:password_reset_complete')), 
        name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

This order is necessary because *'django.contrib.auth.urls'*
already contains *'reset/< uidb64>/< token>/'*. As a result, your code is not running.